entities cant move due to falsely flagged as blocked by player
the entities wont move as they are checking for another entity on the tile they try to move to and falsely return with a log saying they cant move due to the space being occupied by the player, despite it being an empty tile
trying to write code that blocks the entities from moving if the space is occupied by another entity, they all say 'blocked by player' when trying to move into an empty space
perform(engine: Engine, entity: Entity) {
    const destX = entity.x + this.dx;   //}calculates player destination
    const destY = entity.y + this.dy;   //}

    //----------------------------------player's turn-----------------------

    if (!engine.gameMap.isInBounds(destX, destY)) return;       //checks destination, if not in bounds: return
    if (!engine.gameMap.tiles[destY][destX].walkable) return;   //checks destination, if not on walkable tile: return
    if (engine.entityAtPosition(destX, destY) !== null && engine.entityAtPosition(destX, destY) !== undefined) {
        entity.h = entity.h - engine.entityAtPosition(destX, destY)?.attk
        console.log(entity.name + " attacks " + engine.entityAtPosition(destX, destY)?.name + " for " + entity.attk + " damage")
        entityTurn();   //enemy turn
    } else {     //^checks destination, if occupied by an entity: attack
        entity.move(this.dx, this.dy);      //if not attacking, move
        console.log(entity.name + " moves to " + entity.x + ", " + entity.y)
        entityTurn();   //enemy turn
    }
    //----------------------------------enemy's turn------------------------
    function entityTurn() {
        engine.entities.forEach((e) => {        //enemy pathfinding (enemies can move diagonally)
            if (e.name !== 'player') {                 //every entity other than the player
                console.log("-----" + e.name + "'s turn-----")
                const distanceToPlayer = Math.abs(e.x - engine.player.x) + Math.abs(e.y - engine.player.y);
                const dirX = Math.sign(engine.player.x - e.x);  //}maths to calculate difference in position from player. math.sign returns -1 if negative, 0 if 0, 1 if positive
                const dirY = Math.sign(engine.player.y - e.y);  //}
                if (distanceToPlayer < 10) {
                    console.log(e.name + " sees player")
                    if (!engine.gameMap.isInBounds(destX, destY)) { console.log("not in bounds"); return };                         //checks destination, if not in bounds: return
                    if (!engine.gameMap.tiles[destY][destX].walkable) { console.log("tile not walkable"); return };                 //checks destination, if not on walkable tile: return
                    if (engine.entityAtPosition(destX, destY) !== null && engine.entityAtPosition(destX, destY) !== undefined) {    //checks destination, if occupied by an entity: return
                        console.log("space occupied by " + engine.entityAtPosition(destX, destY)?.name); return
                    };
                    e.move(dirX, dirY);
                    console.log(e.name + " moves to " + e.x + ", " + e.y)
                }
            }
        });
        console.log("-----player's turn-----")
    }
}

entityAtPosition(x: number, y: number): Entity | null {
    return this.entities.find((e) => e.x === x && e.y === y) || null;
}


This isn't the right place to whine, but I don't have enough reputation to make a comment, sorry. I hope it's alright to ask you for more context in your code.
My best guess is, you're not calculating destX and destY correctly because this.dx and this.dy are in some cases showing up as 0 when you're listening for keyDown, keyUp, or events concurrently to your calls to your [perform] function. When this.dx and this.dy are 0, it would explain why the [entityAtPosition] function keeps finding and returning your player as the return value, which would then explain why the long [if] statement at line 9 is evaluating to true, leading to the rest of the code in [entityTurn] running correctly until the problem you presented at line 31.
Of course, this is all guesswork. If you could provide enough code for me to reproduce the problem locally on my browser, I'd appreciate it and hopefully someone can get you a better answer with concrete facts. Thanks and good luck.
If, by some odd happening, my guess was correct, then the way to fix your problem would probably involve something like replacing this.dx with the keydown/keyup/whatever event's intended direction's delta in the x and y directions, e.g. 'w' corresponds to {x, (y-1)}, 'a' corresponds to {(x-1), y}, 's' corresponds to... I don't assume to know your key binding design.
